# regex for password field in bootstrapvalidator

Tags: regex, passwords

I want to validate a string using in bootstrapvalidator. String must contain

Minimum of 6 characters.

maximum 12 characters

Must contains atleast one numeral.

Must contain atleast one capital letter.

Must contain atleast one special characters

How can I do that? Can anyone show me the regular expression to do that?

I am already have this:

```
regexp:
       {
         regexp: "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{6,12}",

        message: 'The password should contain Minimum 6 and Maximum 12 characters at least 1 Uppercase Alphabet, 1 Lowercase Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character:'
       }
```

But if i enter correct password requirements also it is showing redcolor and it is not changing to green color

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Also, the [tag:bootstrap] tag is for *"a series of procedures run when an application starts up or a request over the web is received."*, so I don't think that it's the tag you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[$@!%?&]).{6,12}$/
```

Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot) for more information! Try to search the website for a solution before posting a question.

Comment: i checked before posting question but it is not workinjg with bootstrapvalidator

Comment: Try `/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[$@!%?&]).{6,12}$/` ?

Comment: Hm.. Strange? It should. I tested it on Java and Javascript, and they work the same way than the Bootstrapvalidator. Are you sure that the **code** around leading to the validation works?

Comment: Now it is working. the problem is i put regex within quotes. now i fixed the bug. it is working fine. thank you