# How do i check string to contain only letter(Uppercase & Lowercase) and at least one number only

Tags: java, regex, passwords

I'm wondering how do i write a regex to check a string contain at least one uppercase and numbers and does not contain any symbols?

example:

```
String str = "%$!@asdas"

String str2 = "He110W0rLd"
```

I want it to reject `str` however accept `str2`.

It give me this JEES
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for Password Must be contain at least 8 characters, least 1 number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot)

Comment: `string.matches("(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z\\d]+");`

Comment: @anubhava that's more an answer than a comment ;-)

Comment: @anubhava I think you meant `\d` instead of `\\d` because he does want at least one number as well

Comment: yup i want at least 1 number

Comment: so do i just put in \d instead of \\d? JEES

Comment: Thanks to @anubhava for *escaping* `\d` +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @anubhava comment, try this:

As JAVA String:

```
"(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z\\d]+"
```

As Regular Expression:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z\d]+
```

This site can help http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Hello : No

He11o : Yes

heLl1o : Yes

hello : No

3424234 : No

**UPDATE:**
The upper Regex would take `HELLO1` as *acceptable*, because it is not forcing a lowercase, to add this check too the JAVA string would be:

```
"(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])[a-zA-Z\\d]+"
```

Comment: I don't know about JAVA string.matches actually just the regular expression this why, i hope it is working now

Comment: Ok!! finally god!!! was figuring this out keep on reading and i don't understand the regex.. haha thank you so much JEES && anubhava

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        names.add("");
        names.add("%$!@asdas"); // Incorrect
        names.add("He110W0rLd");
        names.add("Techyshy");
        names.add("TechyShy123");
        names.add("Techy$hy123-"); // Incorrect

        String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
        // Use "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"  if blank input is also a valid input. 

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        for (String name : names) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
            System.out.println(matcher.matches());
        }
    }
}

Output:

false
false
true
true
true
false
```