# Expression not working for underscore though included

Tags: javascript, regex

Conditions for password

1. Minimum length should be 7
2. It must contain at-least one Capital letter
3. It must contain at-least one numeric
4. It must contain at-least one special character

`/^(?=.{7,50}$)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*_].*/`

It is working for passwords Mouse@123 but not working for Mouse_123

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for Password Must be contain at least 8 characters, least 1 number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited my question.pls suggest

Answer (score 1):

Your regex can be simplified to this:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&_])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%^&_]{7,50}$/
```

You need not have `(?=.*{7,50}$)` lookahead as that can be done outside as well. Besides requirement of at least one small letter is not there in your question.