# javascript regex not working: atleast one 0-9, one a-z, one A-Z, one from $\-_. +!*'()

Tags: javascript, regex

this regex is making me crazy. i thought it would work. but it does not match anything in  [link here](https://regex101.com/r/vU8eV7/8)

regex is:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$\-_. +!*'()])[a-zA-Z0-9$\-_. +!*'()]*$
```

requirement is:

starts with a-zA-Z
must have: one lowercase, one uppercase, one from given spcl chars ONLY (anything else is invalid), and finally between 10 and 40 chars long.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot

Comment: there were trailing `\n` in your regex..removed it and it works:-https://regex101.com/r/vU8eV7/10

Comment: hi, how to use the same constraints/regex in perl to verify? I used the same regex string, but it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with `MULTILINE` `m` flag:

```
/^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[-$_. +!*'()])[\w$. +!*'()-]{9,39}$/mg
```

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vU8eV7/9)

**Using `{9,39}` instead of `{10,40}` because you have already matched one character `[a-zA-Z]` at start.**

Comment: thx, i dint realize of several <newline> chars at end. and also i missed the 9,39 thx !

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out
`^.(?=.{10,40})(?=.\d)(?=.[a-zA-Z]).$`