# Regex expression not working for password validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to develop a regex pattern for password with following conditions
 1) atleast  1 Uppercase character
2) atleast 3 lower case characters
3) atleast  1 digit
4) atleast 1 Special character
5) Minimum length should be 8 characters.
This is my javascript function. Can somebody help me with the expression. Thanks

```
validatePassword : function(password){
        if(this.isEmpty(password))
        {
            return false;
        }
        var regex = /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8}$/;
        if(!regex.test(password))
        {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Why the specific requirement of at least 3 lowercase characters? You're complicating it for both you as developer and the user who will have to pick a password matching your very specific rules. Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21456918/1276128), where you can find very similar regex (at least 1 lowercase, uppercase, digit special character and length of 8+). Also some simplifications, you don't need to check for empty as this regex will fail in that case, and you can just use `return regex.text(password)`.

Comment: @marko.. thanks...that helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s]).{8,}$/
```

This regex will enforce these rules:

• At least one upper case
• At least three lower case
• At least one digit
• At least one special character
• Minimum 8 in length

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2bv9zn0y/77/)

Comment: Wouldn't the `{2,}` be at least 2 lowercase characters?

Comment: for atleast 3, it should be {3,}.. isn't it?

Comment: you want to use `.*` instead of `.?` as you want the lookahead to match any number of characters before the lookahead specific match. The lower case match should be `(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})`.

Comment: @chan if you used {3,} lower case validation must be 4 characters instead, you can see the outcome above link.

Comment: @timolawl thanks for another answer. I updated the code