# Number Counter in Yii For Password Validation

Tags: php, yii

I want to validate the passwords of users on my website with minimum length of 8 characters, But in these 8 characters i want how many numbers inserted on password, if there are less than 2 numbers in password then it will show that the password is incorrect.?

Example password 1: `aCxR2Vgy` In correct password

Example password 2: `a7x45e7m` Correct Password

How do i perform this? any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your **password attribute** as `password`.

Pass this pattern. It will check for minimum 2 numeric digit and password length of 8. You can pass any message there according to your need.

In **model**, use this line.

```
['password', 'match', 'pattern'=>"^(?=.*?[0-9]{2}).{8,}$",'message'=>'Your password should contain atleast 2 digit and password length must be of 8'],
```

For more info, please click [Regex Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot).