# Regex for Password Validation

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression to validate passwords on following:

- Passwords must be minimum 7 characters, maximum 50 characters
- Passwords must contain characters from at least three of the following four categories:

  1. English uppercase alphabet characters (A–Z)
  2. English lowercase alphabet characters (a–z)
  3. Base 10 digits (0–9)
  4. Non-alphanumeric characters (for example, !$#,%)

My try on this is as follows:

```
^.*(?=.{7,50})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).*$
```

This doesn't check special characters, and I am not getting how to make it that passwords must contain characters from at least three of the following four categories.

Can anyone help to suggest a regular expression to validate this password policy?

Comment: Is there some reason this needs to be a regex?  Each of your constraints could be implemented with builtin functions, or at most, a few lines of trivial code, which would be much more understandable and maintainable than a regex solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Description

`^(?:(?=.*?[A-Z])(?:(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[-!@#$%^&*()_[\]{},.<>+=])|(?=.*?[a-z])(?:(?=.*?[0-9])|(?=.*?[-!@#$%^&*()_[\]{},.<>+=])))|(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[-!@#$%^&*()_[\]{},.<>+=]))[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*()_[\]{},.<>+=-]{7,50}$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

To see the image better, you can right click the image and select view in new window.

This regex will do the following

- Require the string to be 7 - 50 characters long
- Allow the string to be contain `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, and `!@#$%^&*()_[\]{},.<>+=-` characters
- Require at least one character from any three of the following cases

  1. English uppercase alphabet characters `A–Z`
  2. English lowercase alphabet characters `a–z`
  3. Base 10 digits `0–9`
  4. Non-alphanumeric characters  `!@#$%^&*()_[]{},.<>+=-`

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/jR9cC7/1

**Sample Text**

```
         1         2         3         4         5        6
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890124567890
aaaaAAAA1111
aaaaBBBBBBB
AAAAaaaa__
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!A
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!A
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!AA
```

**Allowed Strings**

```
aaaaAAAA1111
AAAAaaaa__
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!A
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                                 times (matching the least amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                                 times (matching the least amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [-                       any character of: '-', '!', '@',
        !@#$%^&*()_[\]           '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(',
        {},.<>+=]                ')', '_', '[', '\]', '{', '}', ',',
                                 '.', '<', '>', '+', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                                 times (matching the least amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                                   times (matching the least amount
                                   possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                                   times (matching the least amount
                                   possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [-                       any character of: '-', '!', '@',
          !@#$%^&*()_[             '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(',
          \]{},.<>+=]              ')', '_', '[', '\]', '{', '}',
                                   ',', '.', '<', '>', '+', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [-                       any character of: '-', '!', '@', '#',
      !@#$%^&*()_[\]{}         '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')',
      ,.<>+=]                  '_', '[', '\]', '{', '}', ',', '.',
                               '<', '>', '+', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z0-                any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
  9!@#$%^&*()_[\]{},.<     '0' to '9', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^',
  >+=-]{7,50}              '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '[', '\]', '{',
                           '}', ',', '.', '<', '>', '+', '=', '-'
                           (between 7 and 50 times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add multiple conditions in one regex we use pipe or brackets 
/(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex2)/ or  (regex1)(regex2)

Each one of the regex conditions is quite basic, and there are a lot of examples for each of the conditions you asked.

you can look here:

[Regex for Password Must be contain at least 8 characters, least 1 number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot)