# Regex optional and group

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

The pattern should match when there is at least 1 numeric OR 1 special character AND a total length of 8 or more.

It partially works but only if the special character or numeric values are at the beginning.

So far I have:

```
/([\d]|[!@#$%^&*()_+])([a-z]).{8,}/
```

Comment: Just so you know, `[A-z]` also contains the characters ``[\]^`_``

Comment: Good point, thanks will drop it to a-z.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for Password Must be contain at least 8 characters, least 1 number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot)

Comment: *"only if the special character or numeric values are at the beginning."* - Because you are only checking them at the beginning `([\d]|[!@#$%^&*()_+])` is the first character only, then `([a-z])` is the second. Then `{8,}` is only for the `.`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I'm pretty sure he already knows and understands that, but just doesn't know how to specify what he wants

Comment: That's ok. Appreciate the help, every time I work with regex I regret not giving it more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why overcomplicate a `RegExp`? Sure it's possible, but you have to specify every permutation of possible combinations of characters that match those requirements. Just do this:

```
if (/[\d!@#$%^&*()_+]/.test(string) && string.length >= 8) { ... }
```

Comment: The regex can also just be: `/[\d!@#$%^&*()_+]/`

Comment: Oh true, I'll fix that. I just copied his regexp

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it backwards, don't try to positively match special characters, that limits what people can/must use. Instead, match something you consider to be *not* not special, e.g.:

```
pw.length >= 8 && /\d/.test(pw) && /[^a-z\d\x20]/i.test(pw)
```

Than checks length, presence of a digit, then presence of a character that's not alphanumeric nor a space (the `i` flag makes it case-insensitive). You may also want to disallow spaces and other control characters that are not usually able to be typed on a keyboard (prevents people pasting in junk):

```
&& !/[\x00-\x20]/.test(pw)
```