# When to use positive lookarounds in Regex?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

Can someone explain to me, why/when I should use **positive** lookarounds in Regex? For negative lookarounds I can think of scenarios where they are the only solution, but for positive lookarounds I don't see why to use them, when their result can also be produced by using capture groups.

For example:

Input: `Bus: red, Car: blue`

I want to color of the car.

With lookaround: `(?<=Car: )\w+`
With capture group: `Car: (\w+)`

Both Regex archive the same result - direct access to the color-match. So are there cases which can only be solved by positive lookarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCRE is used not only in PHP, the library is used in a variety of tools and languages, where you do not always have easy access to captured groups.

In some of them, a lookbehind is the easiest way to, say, split a string (with `strsplit` in R), or work around the problems with accessing submatches.

PCRE lookbehind is "crippled" in a way, that is, it is fixed-width, and is thus really not that full-fledged. However, here is [an interesting case](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind): a positive lookbehind is used *after* the match increasing performance: `\d{3}(?<=USD\d{3})`. Here, the check only starts after we matched 3 digits, no need to check `U`, then `S`, then `D`, then digits.

As for a positive lookahead, it is used in a lot of scenarios:

- Set conditions on the string matched (see Dmitry's answer, also e.g. `^(?=.*\d)` will require at least 1 digit in the string)
- *Overlapping matches* are possible (e.g. `-\d+(?=-|$)` will find 3 matches in `-1-2-3`)

Answer (score 2):

Positive lookarounds may be useful when imposing additional conditions on a pattern without affecting the main pattern.

For instance, you may need to check if a string contains a red bus or a blue car *and is no longer than 20 charactes:*

```
^(?=.{0,20}$).*(?:Bus: red|Car: blue)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iQ4uL4/1

More examples of this sort can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21456918/4295017

Comment: Just one more question. Why do you write the lookahead in front of the main regex-pattern? I thought I had to write lookaheads as also lookbehinds after/right to the regex pattern to that it refers?!

Comment: @netblognet, actually, it's after the `^` pattern, so this `^` is the pattern the lookahead is tied to.