# Regex for Password Validation Field

Tags: javascript, java, php, regex

I'm trying to validate a password in my application by using `Regex`. I don't have much idea of Regex, This is what i got.

```
"^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$"
```

This expression is also checking `Special Character`, and 1 upper case character in password.

I need a Regex that full fills following criteria.

1. Password Must be at least 8 characters Long.
2. Password must contain 1 Letter
3. Password must contain 1 Number
4. Password should not contain any special Character.

Comment: The regex is taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot, right? So, what have you tried to adapt it to your scenario?

Comment: What's wrong with special characters?

Comment: I don't need special characters in the text field. Is  there any possibility we can add such conditions through regex?

Comment: So take out `(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])` but I don't know why you don't want to allow them, seems like a bad idea.. `(?=.*?[A-Z])` has a capital letter. `(?=.*?[a-z])` lowercase letter. `(?=.*?[0-9])` number. `.{8,}` over 8 characters or longer. There are sites that breakdown regexs, take a look at https://regex101.com/r/Bqu4bv/1 on the right side.

Comment: Thanks @chris85, let me try that..

Comment: @chris85: You might want to edit [anubhava's original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19605207/3832970) :)

Comment: Yup, its working fine, but i am very poor in understanding Regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated it.

Comment: @Kirmani88 That's why the regex101 can be useful. It breaks down every part of the regular expression and explains it.

Comment: Yes, I am looking into it. Thanks a lot for this reference site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't claim to be a regex master, but for the password criteria you describe, you could use:

`/^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/` to test for conditions 2, 3, and 4.

For condition 1, I would just check the string length property to make sure it's at least 8 characters.

Note that in your current regex, you are requiring at least one uppercase letter, at least one lowercase letter, at least one digit, and at least one of the specified special characters (#?!@$%^&*-). Hope this helps.