# How do I check if a string contains at least one number, letter, and character that is neither a number or letter?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, numbers, letter

The language is javascript.

Strings that would pass:

> JavaScript1*
>
> Pu54 325
>
> ()9c

Strings that would not pass:

> 654fff
>
> %^(dFE

I tried the following:

```
var matches = password.match(/\d+/g);
if(matches != null)
 {
        //password contains a number
        //check to see if string contains a letter
        if(password.match(/[a-z]/i))
        {
            //string contains a letter and a number
        }
 }
```

Comment: Yes. I tried many things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Regex:

I took it from here: [Regex for Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot)

```
var checkPassword = function(password){
    return !!password.match(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%* #+=\(\)\^?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%* #+=\(\)\^?&]{3,}$/);
};
```

I use this Regex:

Minimum 3 characters at least 1 Alphabet, 1 Number and 1 Special Character:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%* #=+\(\)\^?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%* #=+\(\)\^?&]{3,}$"
```

This regex will enforce these rules:

At least one English letter, (?=.*?[A-Za-z])

At least one digit, (?=.*\d)

At least one special character, (?=.*[$@$!%* #+=()\^?&]) Add more if you like...

Minimum length of 3 characters (?=.*[$@$!%* #?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%* #+=()\^?&]{3,} include spaces

If you want to add more special characters, you can add it to the Regex like I have added '(' (you need to add it in two places).

And for those of you who ask yourself what are those two exclamation points, here is the answer: [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @michael-drum The 2 exclamation points are for the function to always return boolean - look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Comment: @michael-drum So why didn't you mark this answer as the "Answer to your question"?

Comment: So far, I am aware that it doesn't work with spaces or "+"s. A string with those characters should return true;

Comment: @michael-drum you should add them to the Special Characters list - like this /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%* #+=?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%* #+=?&]{3,}$/

Comment: @michael-drum check it now, after my last update. I have added space and +, =, ( and ) to the Regexp - if you need more special characters add them to the Regexp like I did.

Comment: It works fine for me. Please give me some examples that don't work for you