# Regular expression for password validation?

Tags: html, regex

I need regex for a password that has:

- at least one non letter or digit character.
- at least one lowercase ('a'-'z').
- at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z').

I need it for HTML pattern attribute.

I tried this:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

but it accepts only a, for example. 
also this:

```
"[A-Za-z0-9]"
```

accepts one character

Comment: Try doing 3 different regex's, one for each instance: number, uppercase letter, lowercase letter

Comment: This has been asked many times on SO. Just use the search function!

Comment: You can see same question and answer from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: There is even an example on w3schools on the page for validations using the pattern attribute. `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}`, change `{8,}` to `+` if you don't care about length - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex: `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/gm`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/piiHmq/1/)

Regex: `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$/gm`

[Regex demo for specific length](https://regex101.com/r/piiHmq/2/)

Comment: And where can I specify the length for the whole password, please?

Comment: Adding a new regex in which you can specify length as well.

Comment: Added new expression in which you can specify any length you want. In the above example i have used length `10`. You can change it according to your requirement.