# RegEx - Length limited and alphanumeric

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex which requires both alphabetic and numeric characters (not just numeric or just alphabetic) and is a specific length.

I know this could be done by using two regex or other program code to check the length, but I want to know if it's possible just by using one regex.

This captures both but isn't limited by length.

```
([0-9]+[a-z]+|[a-z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-z]*
```

This unfortunately doesn't work

```
(([0-9]+[a-z]+|[a-z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-z]){10}
```

Comment: At least related, not sure about dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21456918/3836111

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out

Comment: [`^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z\d]{10}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/xcTWyw/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use positive look-ahead `?=` to verify the presence of alphabets and digits and capture both using limit `{10}`

[`^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z\d]{10}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/xcTWyw/2)

Demo

```js
const regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z\d]{10}$)/;
console.log(regex.test('abcdefghi9'));
console.log(regex.test('211212jknN'));
console.log(regex.test('211212jknnd')); // extra length 
console.log(regex.test('2121212122'));  // no alphabets
console.log(regex.test('csdcdcdcdc'));   // no digits
```

---

update : To find all the matches in single line use

[`\b(?=[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{10}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/i1F34O/1)

`(?=[a-zA-Z]+\d` : either one or more `a-zA-Z` and a digit

`|\d+[a-zA-Z])`  : or one or more digits and one `a-zA-Z`

Demo

```js
const regex = /\b(?=[a-zA-Z]+\d|\d+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{10}\b/g;
const str = 'sasas12212 aaaaaaaaaa 211212jknn 211212jknnd 2121212122 csdcdcdcd1 csdcdcdc12';
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: The remaining problem I have is - what I didn't clarify in my question - when the text string contains many other words or just spaces. For instance `regex.test('abcdefghij 1234')` with the added space would get a match. (Omitting the `^` and `$`)

Comment: To clarify via [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vfhqEO/1) when the string is not multi-line and contains spaces

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. this case Length=3

```
^(?=.{3,3}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```