# Regex requirement

Tags: angularjs, regex

I was working on a regex which fulfills below criteria. Kindly suggest.

1. Must have at least 1 numeric character
2. Sequential numbers are not allowed
3. All characters cannot be the same
4. Minimum of 4 alphanumeric characters allowed
5. Allow special characters #&()_+[]:;',/.\-" *

Comment: checkout this http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: checkout this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot

Comment: @Jayant patil I already tried these but no go

Comment: @SrishtiKishore I cannot see any effort you have done so far. Please, edit your question and add sample code.

Comment: @Scheff I have made below regex which is fulfilling three conditions : 1,4 and 5. Below is the regex:
^(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W]){0,})(?!.*\s).{4,}$.

m looking for below regex:
Sequential numbers are not allowed
All characters cannot be the same

Comment: @SrishtiKishore Please, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42827017/edit) your question and add the sample code. Please, use the `{}` button in the toolbar of the editor to format it.

Comment: @SrishtiKishore I played with this for a while based on your and @AfzalPatel s efforts. All I got is this pattern for digits I used to match 2. requirement: `(0|(?<!0)1|(?<!1)2|(?<!2)3|(?<!3)4|(?<!4)5|(?<!5)6|(?<!6)7|(?<!7)8|(?<!8)9|9)`. I struggled trying to combine this with the 3. and 4. requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z\d])[\w@#&*+=-]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qW3oQ8/1

Comment: I tried with this. This is fulfilling some conditions not all:   ^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W]){1,})(?!.*\s).{8,}$

Comment: check demo and make pattern as your condition

Comment: the above regex is not fullfilling second condition `Sequential numbers are not allowed` example i tried `mayur1234`