# Regular Expression Password Sylius (regex)

Tags: php, regex, symfony, bundle, sylius

I'd like to set a pattern for the password on Sylius. 
I'd like :

1. 8 characters (min)
2. 1 lowercase (min)
3. 1 uppercase(min)

So I made this regular expression :

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$
```

However I don't know where I have to put it to set my password condition

Thank you for your time

Comment: [Dot is a highly misused character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). Your regex is incorrect. `.` will allow unwanted characters. Instead use a character class of allowed characters like `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

Comment: Hope my post will help you out..

Comment: Correct Horse Battery Staple

Comment: @CD001 whats that ? *Horse Battery Staple*

Comment: @SahilGulati : https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for Password Must be contain at least 8 characters, least 1 number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot)

Comment: @N.Jourdan Thanks for accepting my answer friend.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this regex will help you out.

**Regex:** `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$`

> **1.** `^` starting of string
>
> **2.** `(?=.*[a-z])` Positive look ahead for lowercase character
>
> **3.** `(?=.*[A-Z])` Positive look ahead for uppercase character
>
> **4.** `.{8,}$` Match `8` or more characters till the end.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/6RZQjK/1)

**PHP code:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/791587)

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$string="SahilGul";
if(preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/', $string))
{
    echo "Password pattern matched";
}
```