# Multiple validation groups in an Angular form group

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want some specific validations in a form and I cannot find an elegant way of doing so. Let's say I have a field, that can satisfy one of a few groups of validation constraints to be valid? The specific validation for a password I want is:

- required
- max length 256 characters
- min length 10 characters
- Requires at least one integer
- Requires at least one symbol
- Requires at least one capital letter

OR

- required
- max length 256 characters
- min length 32 characters

I want validation to accept either of these groups for the same field. Is there an elegant way to do this with angular forms?

Comment: what i am guessing is that you want a validator that has all the validation and you can plug and play the validations you want ? if this is the case you can have a different class for your validator and then use the same function call in your formbuilder

Answer (score 0):

> you can set validation like that. and you can set pattern for
>   numeric, symbol and alpha

```
   this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)], Validators.minLength(10) , Validators.pattern('^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{10,}$')],
    });
```

pattern found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot)