# regex for password 6-12 chars one digit, one uppercase

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to check user password with this regular exp:

```
$regex='/^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9@])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9@]{6,12}$/';

if(isset($_POST['password']) && strlen($_POST['password'])>=6 && 
strlen($_POST['password']<=12) && preg_match($regex, $_POST['password'])){

echo 'ok';
}else{echo 'invalid password';}
```

I'd like the password to be from 6 to 12 chars, at least one digit and at least one Uppercase.

It doesn't work if the password is something like **12Hello** instead it works with **Hello12** , someone could please help?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't lend itself to a **clean** regular expression. It'll have to be very much brute-force.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It echoes `ok` for both `12Hello` and `Hello12`, unless you're doing something other than what or in addition to you've posted. [Here's a working demo](https://3v4l.org/N4FVL). By the way, please try formatting your code before posting. The code you posted is difficult to read, which leads to errors.

Comment: There are good examples on this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-be-contain-at-least-8-characters-least-1-number-and-bot

Comment: Please stop doing this in 2017 - allow arbitrary input, and then **hash** to the desired password length. Just use a library that tells your users how easy it is to hack their password (ideally, of the "this password can be cracked in 2 seconds, please pick a better one") and then accept whatever the hell they pick that is strong enough. There is literally no reason to roll your own code here, *we already figured this out for you, in your favourite language, use that*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:-

Minimum 6 character

Atleast 1 uppercase character

At least one digit

Expression:

```
"/^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,12}$/"
```

Comment: After the edits this answer is now the same as mine, although lacking a description.

Comment: Sorry chris,when i post my answer..really i didnt check your answer above.

Comment: The `?` here `.*?` is redundant. `*` is 0 or more anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your character class is too broad. You need to check for things separately.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{6,12}$
```

`(?=.*[A-Z])` is at least one upper case character.
`(?=.*\d)` is at least one number
and `.{6,12}` is 6-12 characters (that aren't new lines)
The `^$` are anchors ensuring the full string matches.

In your regex your character class `[A-Za-z0-9@]` allows an uppercase character, lowercase, number, or `@` (which doesn't ensure you have 1 uppercase character). You also don't need the `strlen` functions if using this regex.