# How can I perform password complexity validation on devise without having to install other gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am using devise for authentication in a rails app. I want to add validation for some password complexity rules. It seems I don't have access to the raw password at the model level before it has been hashed. As such, I cannot validate that the raw password provided conforms to the password complexity rules that I have set. The only other way I can do this is at the controller-level. However, I'm afraid that that approach will pollute my controller. Any ideas about how I can perform the validation without having to install any other gem?

Answer (score 3):

The best option for create complex passwords without additional gems and it also works on rails 6.0.3.2 ruby 2.7.1
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-simple-password-complexity-requirements

### Solution from Devise wiki (above link)

Here is a simple method of adding a password strength / complexity requirement to devise without using devise security extension (using extension is recommended.)

Example: add the following line to app/models/user.rb. Edit Regex to your liking

```rb
  validate :password_complexity
  
  def password_complexity
    # Regexp extracted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a
    return if password.blank? || password =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,70}$/

    errors.add :password, 'Complexity requirement not met. Length should be 8-70 characters and include: 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 digit and 1 special character'
  end
```

Afterwards, password created by the user (or admin) must meet the regex requirements.

If the password length is checked by another method (such as config.password_length), this suits better:

```rb
  def password_complexity
    # Regexp extracted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a
    return if password.blank? || password =~ /(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])/

    errors.add :password, 'Complexity requirement not met. Please use: 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 digit and 1 special character'
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple method of adding a password strength / complexity requirement at the model level.

```
#app/models/user.rb

validate :password_complexity

def password_complexity
  if password.present?
     if !password.match(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/) 
       errors.add :password, "Password complexity requirement not met"
     end
  end
end
```

**Duplication:**
[Devise custom password validation leads invalid user in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56419658/devise-custom-password-validation-leads-invalid-user-in-console/56419835)

**Official docs:**
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-simple-password-complexity-requirements

Comment: Hey, I tried this but ran into a small problem: `password` is actually the `encrypted_password`. Therefore, with this approach, it appears that I'd be validating the encrypted_password instead of the raw password.

Comment: This is also written in the Devise page itself: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Set-up-simple-password-complexity-requirements @monk - did it work for you?

Comment: how is this supposed to work if password is encrypted hash?