# How to make validation username using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to create a `preg_match` function to validate my username, my code below not working perfectly, especially on `Must contain at least 4 letter lowercase` rules and `number not more than 4 character and place behind letter`

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{4,12}/', $_POST['username']))
```

Here are my username rules that I want to work :

- Only contain letter and numbers but number is not reqired
- Must contain at least 4 letter lowercase
- Number not more than 4 character and place behind letter
- Must be 4-12 characters

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: can sites stop forcing me to abide by arbitrary rules for my user-name please.

Comment: Tell us; what isn't working the way you'd like it to? What results are you presently getting, as opposed to the desired results? You didn't describe the problem.

Comment: we don't read minds, please remember that in case you're still here. I myself have left since it's unclear what it is you're asking.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19605207/4333555, it's not exactly what your asking but it can lead you there. Also don't forget closing anchor.

Comment: @chris hey stranger, long time no see. Hope all is well your way, *cheers* (I only revisited this post to see if there was any update/comments left). Alas, no.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Ah, helllo Fred. Yea, kinda getting busy with side projects, havent been around much.

Comment: @chris85 Kind of the same here; got me a fine issue with a server moving to a new location and has been a sort of nightmare but I am managing. There's always more than one way to skin a cat, as it were ;-) I didn't think you'd know who I was, given I changed my profile name; it's more fitting for me *lol!* cheers man, take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You match these criteria, maybe this will be an option:

[`^[a-z](?=(?:[a-z]*\d){0,4}(?![a-z]*\d))(?=[a-z\d]{3,11}$)[a-z\d]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/6tjXKO/1/)

**This will match**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match a lowercase character `[a-z]`
- A positive lookahead `(?=` which asserts that what follows is

  - A non capturing group `(?:`
  - Which will match a lowercase character zero or more times followed by a digit `[a-z]*\d`
  - Close non capturing group and repeat that from 0 to 4 times `){0,4}`
  - A negative lookahead `(?!` Which asserts that what follows is not
  - A lowercase character zero or more times followed by a digit `[a-z\d]*`
  - Close negative lookahead `)`
- Close positive lookahead `)`
- Positive lookahead `(?=` which asserts that what follows is

  - Match a lowercase character or a digit from 3 till 11 times till the end of the string `(?=[a-z\d]{3,11}$)`
- Close positive lookahead `)`
- Match a lowercase character or a digit till the end of the string `[a-z\d]+$`

[Out php example](https://3v4l.org/2mWEk)

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`^[a-z]{4,8}[0-9]{0,4}$|^[a-z]{4,12}$`](https://regex101.com/r/IrkSkh/1)

Details:

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line
- `$` Asserts position at the end of a line
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `{n,m}` Matches between `n` and `m` times
- `|` Or

**PHP code**:

```
$strings=['testtesttest', 'testtesttestr', 'test12345', 'testtest1234', 'testte123432'];

foreach($strings as $string){
    $match = preg_match('~^[a-z]{4,8}[0-9]{0,4}$|^[a-z]{4,12}$~', $string);
    echo ($string . ' => len: (' . strlen($string) . ') ' .($match ? 'true' : 'false')."\n");
}
```

Output:

```
testtesttest => len: (12) true
testtesttestr => len: (13) false
test12345 => len: (9) false
testtest1234 => len: (12) true
testte123432 => len: (12) false
```

[Code demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f43b60798052dea156f227aec066983e13a3d8e)