# Regex String must contain a special character

Tags: c#

The string I want to check must have a special character. I've been looking for it here in the forum, but I found only this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a) and this does not really help me

Comment: If that thread is no help then I think you need to explain a bit (quite a lot) more about what you are trying to do. With what you've tried already.

Comment: welcome to SO ... please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help about asking your question in a way suitable for SO

Comment: `[#?!@$%^&*-]` or something like this

Answer (score 1):

When you

> want to check must have a **special character**

You have to decide what the *special character* is (e.g. are `'{'`, `TAB`, `.` are special ones?). There are several options. Let's declare (*positive*)

```
 #?!@$%^&*-
```

to be the only special characters. In this case we can check

```
 string special = "#?!@$%^&*-";

 bool hasSpecial = Regex.IsMatch(source, $"[{Regex.Escape(special)}]+");
```

Or (*Linq*)

```
 bool hasSpecial = source.Any(c => special.Contains(c));
```

On the contrary, we can say (*negative* declaration) that the special character is anyone which is not *alphanumeric*.

```
 bool hasSpecial = Regex.IsMatch(source, @"\W+");
```

Or (*Linq*)

```
 bool hasSpecial = source.Any(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^.*(?=.*[@#$%^&+=(){}<>!~_*?]).*$
```