# Pattern sometimes matched and sometimes not

Tags: angular, pattern-matching

I've implemented a pattern in angular 5 with the following code in the .ts file for password verification. This suppose to do - support minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character. See: [Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)

```
wcodePattern = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z0-9\d$@$-_!%*?&]{8,20}";
```

I see, when I entered a string in the password text box e.g. `Niladri1!` its working however, when I entered a string like `Nopasss123!!`, it shows `User name not valid.`.

Below is the code for angular 5 html:

```
<div *ngIf="wcode.errors?.pattern">User name not valid.</div>
```

I have also tested with the following and it takes string as `Noladris` which suppose to be invalid.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@-_!])[A-Za-z0-9\d@-_!]{8,20}$
```

Anything I missed?

Comment: Did you take the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21456918/3832970? I fixed some issues there just now. Add `$` to the end and remove one `$` inside the character class. Also, put `-` before the closing `]`. `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z0-9@$_!%*?&-]{8,20}$` should work, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9XmaFU/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've added what I have taken as you suggested. Please check the question once again and let me know.

Comment: Sure , that is because you did not escape the hyphen, and [`[@-_]+`](https://regex101.com/r/wtfOoz/1) matches all ASCII letters and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
wcodePattern = '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z0-9@$_!%*?&-]{8,20}$'
```

Or, since you are using it inside a `RegExp` constructor, here is a version for use there:

```
wcodePattern = '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@$_!%*?&-]{8,20}$'
```

Note:

- You must put `-` at the start/end of the character class to match a literal hyphen, or escape it inside
- Backslashes in a string literal must be doubled, else they define escape sequences like `\n`, `\t`, etc.
- `$` must be added at the end of the pattern to "anchor" the match (i.e. match the end of the string to ensure the max char restriction).
- `[$@$]` = `[$@]`  - there is no need repeating the chars inside a character class.