# Regular expression for password in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have used regular expression validator in aspx form.I have used this express `((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{6,15})`,working fine.

I am trying to use same expression in javascript,but that fail why so ?

In javascript

```
var regularExpression  = ((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{6,15})


if (regularExpression.test(newPassword)) {
    alert("Password must be at least 6 characters, not more than 15 characters, and must include at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter, one special character and one numeric digit.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `var regularExpression  = ((?` is invalid syntax, you need delimiters.

Comment: Can u pls correct it out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)

Answer (score 1):

you should use `/` instead of `(` for RegExp

```
var regularExpression  = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{6,15}/;

if (regularExpression.test(newPassword)) {
    alert("Password must be at least 6 characters, not more than 15 characters, and must include at least one upper case letter, one lower case letter, one special character and one numeric digit.");
    return false;
}
```