# Password Regex For Angular 4 fails

Tags: javascript, angular

I have added a regex which will check for  least 8 characters, at least one number, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one special character
This is the regex Used

```
'(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-zd$@$!%*?&].{8,}'
```

The above regex works fine for most of the scenarios but when I use

```
1oB!gb0s5
```

or

```
Pass@123
```

It fails. Can anyone tell me the issue here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a

Comment: You might find [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the portion of your regex which actually consumes the input:

```
[A-Za-zd$@$!%*?&].{8,}
```

This means that the password must *start* with one of the characters in the above character class.  It also means that a valid password must have *nine* or more characters, because the class counts for one, and `{8,}` means 8 or more.  So the following would fail because it does not begin with any such character:

```
1oB!gb0s5
```

The second example you gave fails for a different reason, because it only has 8 characters:

```
Pass@123
```

I don't know exactly what logic you want here.  If you just want to ensure that a password has a lowercase, uppercase, number, and special character, then maybe you can remove the leading character class and just stick with the lookaheads:

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&]).{8,}
```

Here is a demo which shows that your two example passwords would pass using the above pattern.

### Demo