# Getting "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2))" when checking user for roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, rolify

I am using the Rolify Gem on a Rails application. This has worked well until today. I was installing webpacker and stimulus and while doing that ran Bundle Update. This appears to have broken my Rolify functionality.

Examined User model carefully and compared to another app where Rolify is still working. Checked Role model, checked database schema to ensure users_roles table is intact.

Is there anything in a polymorphic relationship that could cause that Argument error?

I apologize if this question is not well formulated, this is my first time asking a question here.

```
u=User.find(1)

=> #<User id: 1, email: "admin@admin.com", created_at: "2019-04-27 17:13:17", updated_at: "2019-06-08 16:24:03", roles_mask: nil, first_name: "admin", last_name: "administrator", authentication_token: "V9rJdmKrhvZxVzBH55wk", email_frequency: nil, last_emailed: nil> 

u.roles

Traceback (most recent call last):
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2))
```

I get the following error: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2))

User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :password_complexity
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  #default_scope { order("last_name, first_name")}
  rolify
#has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_table => :users_roles
  has_many :cohorts_users, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cohorts, :through => :cohorts_users

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, #:registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessor :skip_password_validation, :admin, :student, :rater, :author, :preceptor, :teacher, :auditor
  attribute :email, :string
  after_create :assign_default_role

  def self.import(file, cohort)
    cohort = Cohort.find(cohort.to_i)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      user = new
      user.attributes = row.to_hash
      user.skip_password_validation = true
      user.cohorts << cohort
      user.save!
      #user.invite!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end


  def password_required?
    return false if skip_password_validation
    super
  end

  def full_name
   "#{last_name}, #{first_name}"
  end
def assign_default_role
    self.add_role(:candidate) if self.roles.blank?
  end

private
def self.ransortable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    column_names - ['password_digest']
  end

  # Whitelist the User model attributes for search, except +password_digest+,
  # as above. The +full_name+ ransacker below is included via +_ransackers.keys+
  #
  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ransortable_attributes + _ransackers.keys
  end

  def password_complexity
    # Regexp extracted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a
    return if password.blank? || password =~ /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,70}$/
    errors.add :password, 'Complexity requirement not met. Length should be 8-70 characters and include: 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 digit and 1 special character'
  end
  # Demonstration of using a "ransacker" (a virtual, searchable "column") to
  # allow searching via the full name from concatenated first and last names.
  #
  ransacker :full_name do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
      Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('||',
        parent.table[:first_name], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(' ')),
      parent.table[:last_name])
  end

end
```

Role:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles


belongs_to :resource,
           :polymorphic => true,
           :optional => true


validates :resource_type,
          :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
          :allow_nil => true

def self.defined_roles
  self.all.map { |role| role.name  }
end

scopify
end
```

Comment: paste your Role model and User model here..

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also ran into the same problem but in my case I am adding role.

Comment: No, no solution. I restored to the old gem file and re-bundled without the updates and it all started working again. Not a great solution.

Comment: Mine got fixed as well doing the same. Did you notice any gem that might have caused this? I didn't maybe if you did we could notify the gem maintainer to look out for this error.

Comment: I didn't. When I ran the bundle update it updated a whole bunch of gems. I was tempted to roll them back one at a time to see if I could isolate the culprit but I didn't have time to do so. Please let me know if you find anything else out.

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me was that I had to upgrade my ransack gem to ~ 2.1 per:

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/polyamorous/issues/48 and https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/944