# Regex from regex101.com does not work in mz c# code

Tags: c#, regex

Why regex on regex101.com is not quite identical in C# code?
for example I want to validate a password which must contains:

- At least one upper case
- At least one lower case
- At least one number
- At least one special character
- At least length should be 8 characters or greater

The regex that I use is: `((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8,50000})`

And it works on website.

Here is the [example](https://regex101.com/r/zA6txG/2)

However, when I transfer it to C# code, when I entered correct value such as for example `Testable.345` it shows an validation message (it doesnt pass).
Here is the code in my C#:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string input = Startup();
            GetMatched(input);
        }

        private static string Startup()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter string for regex match: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            return input;
        }

        private static void GetMatched(string input)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            {
                const string digitsRegex = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A - Z])(?=.*\\W).{ 8,50000})";

                Regex regex = new Regex(digitsRegex, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
                string fieldData = input.ToString().Replace(" ", "");


                if (regex.IsMatch(fieldData))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Startup();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The example you used has a different regex. Btw, you can check at the regex101 generated code and see the difference with yours

Comment: Use `string digitsRegex = @"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W).{8,50000}$"`

Comment: On Regex101, you have activated global and multiline

Comment: Oh, I now see that I used PHP standard, and when I used ES standard, it works in C#. Just a question how to avoid those 50000 as maximum input chars, I wanted evrything greater than 8.

Comment: Use `{8,}`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/**
    Requirements: (Must contain at least one of each condition ): 
        a lowercase alpha character, 
        a uppercase alpha character, 
        a numeric character,
        a nonalphanumeric character, 
        minimum string length is 8
**/

(?=^.*[a-z]{1}.*$)(?=^.*[A-Z]{1}.*$)(?=^.*[0-9]{1}.*$)(?=^.*[^0-9a-zA-Z]{1}.*$)(?=.{8})