# How to find $@º[] with regExp in JS

Tags: javascript, exp

i need to see if a string contains at least one number, one english alfabetic character and one of those characters $ @ o [ ]
I am trying this but it doesnt work.

> /^(.*[a-zA-Z].*)(.*[0-9].*)(.*[$@o[]].*)$/.test(strPassword))

I think that the problem is with the special characters, help pls

Comment: It might be simpler just to use `String.prototype.indexOf` for each character you want to find.

Comment: I must use reg Exp, my teacher is my teacher xD

Comment: https://regex101.com/ - There are several sites that can do this, but this site will help you compare your expression to your use cases. it may lend better guidance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a

Comment: Try this. "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,}$"

Comment: In your specific case: `/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@º\[\]]).*$/` would do the job.