# How to pass two different password pattern using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

What regex can pass all of these password patterns

```
At least 1 digit - Mandatory
8 characters long - Mandatory
```

and the password also may include (optional)

```
one or more uppercase or lowercase
one ore more special character
```

I would want both of these 2 password pattern pass

1. Password@2020 / password@2020
2. Password2020 / password2020

**EDIT**

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}|$
```

This works for the second pattern i.e Password2020 / password2020 but what if I would want to allow the user to **OPTIONALLY** add a special character like Password@2020 / password@2020

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a

Comment: Use let myregex = /[Pp]assword@?2020/

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: ^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}|$ this works for password2020 and Password2020, the second option but what if I would want to allow the user to add one or more special characters to their password, not compulsory but still would want to give them an option

Comment: Thd question is too unclear, judging by the rules you just need `/^(?=.{8})\D*\d/` - at least eight chars and at least one digit.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, can we optionally allow the user to add special character to their password, something like password@2020, here @ (the special character) should be optional. Freedom to choose password2020 or password@2020. A regex that can satisfy both these conditions?

Comment: My above regex allows any characters in the input. Please explain the condition you wang to add in words. Please edit the question.

Comment: When you make something optional, then there's no need to encode that in the regex, by definition. Wiktor's regex does it, based on the question as asked.