# Python Password Validation

Tags: python, regex

I try to write a simple Regular Expression that checks for the following conditions:

- At least six characters long
- contains a lowercase letter
- contains an uppercase letter
- contains a number

I tried to work like this:

```
regex = re.compile(r'''([0-9])+([A-Z])+([a-z])+.{6,}''')
```

I found a lot of similar threads, but I would like to know why exactly mine is not working as I intend it too. As I am still new to programming and regex in general I apologize if I missed some trivial stuff right here.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try lookahead assertions? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a

Comment: With your approach you must have at least one digit at the start of your password, followed by an uppercase character and so on. So `"A1xxxx"` won't work. Use lookahead assertions like @Thefourthbird said.

Comment: Thanks! Got it now!

Answer (score 0):

`^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{6,}$`