# Password regex that requires “at least two of” certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

Im working on javascript regex which includes having following conditions. So far with no luck.

-The minimum character count allowed is 8.

-The maximum character count allowed is 64.

-The entered text should include at least two of the following - numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase
letters, Special characters.

-Entering symbols will not be supported.

**So far what I have is this @anubhava answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a).**

`^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$`

**This regex will enforce these rules:**

-At least one upper case English letter, (?=.*?[A-Z])

-At least one lower case English letter, (?=.*?[a-z])

-At least one digit, (?=.*?[0-9])

-At least one special character, (?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])

-Minimum eight in length .{8,63} (with the anchors)

**My Question is how do I satify my 3rd and 4th conditions Which is :-**

-The entered text should include at least two of the following - numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase
letters, Special characters.

-Entering symbols will not be supported.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not possible to do concisely. I'd use programmatic logic instead.

Comment: Any idea on How to do it in .NET?

Comment: `(?=.*?\d.*?\d)` should match “2 numbers”, no?

Comment: Also, consider Unicode categories, as practical, as not everyone uses the same characters..

Comment: For .NET (not sure why the question is tagged JS in that case..), the input can be turned into a historgram based on character class using a simple loop and `char.GetUnicodeCategory` or other method of classification (including more specific rules). Or bypass the histogram with some `string#IndexOf` calls etc.

Comment: Do you want at least two numbers and two lowercase letters and 2 uppercase letters and 2 special characters? Like `11aaBB@@` should be a match?

Comment: What ever user entered it should have minimum of 2 out of these conditons (numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, Special characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]$)(?![a-z]*$)(?![A-Z]*$)(?![0-9]*$)(?![#?!@$%^&*-]*$).{8,64}$
```

The string should not contain any symbol outside the 4 groups of characters

```
^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]$)
```

The string should not consist only of lower letters

```
(?![a-z]*$)
```

The string should not consist only of upper letters

```
(?![A-Z]*$)
```

The string should not consist only of digits

```
(?![0-9]*$)
```

The string should not consist only of special characters

```
(?![#?!@$%^&*-]*$)
```

The string should consist of 8 to 64 characters

```
.{8,64}$
```

#### UPDATED 2020-09-07

#### If the string should contain symbols of at list 3 groups of 4

```
^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]$)((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*-])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*-])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*-])).{8,64}$
```

The string should not contain any symbol outside the 4 groups of characters

```
^(?!.*[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]$)
```

Then 4 variants of 3 groups of 4 that the symbols should be member of:

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])
```

or

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*-])
```

or

```
(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*-])
```

or

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*-])
```

and finally the string should consist of 8 to 64 characters

```
.{8,64}$
```

Comment: Can you update your answer according to  this - The entered text should include at least **three** of the following - numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, Special characters. @J200200831a

Answer (score 1):

```js
var regex =/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,64}$/;

 
function test() {

 if(regex.test(document.getElementById("txtPassword").value)===false)
 {
 alert("Min 8,Max 64,At Least One Uppercase Character,One Lowercase Character,One Numeric Value And One Special Character(!@#$%^&*) Required ");
 }
 else
 {
 alert("Success");
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtPassword" />
<button id="testBtn" onclick=test()>CheckPassword</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Text includes at least **two** of the following - numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, Special characters. No characters outside [A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$|^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$|^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$|^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$|^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$|^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$
```

Text includes at least **three** of the following - numbers, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, Special characters. No characters outside [A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$|^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$|^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$|^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])(?!.*?[^A-Za-z0-9#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,63}$
```