# Minimum 6 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character required in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Minimum 6 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character required.But this regular expression not working for me.Code is given below:

```
$.validator.addMethod("password_regex", function(value, element) 
{
 var password_regex = this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$!%*?&^(){}])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$/.test(value);

 var password_regex = this.optional(element) || /^(?=.{8,})(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[@#$%^&+=]).$/.test(value);

   return password_regex;
        },
```

Comment: so ... what is your question?

Comment: That regular expresion is not working for me. I want Minimum 6 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character required in jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)

Comment: regex pattern will be `"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$"`

Comment: regex pattern will be "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{6,}$" not working it doesn't throw error when upper letter is missing

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help: below code works for me

```js
var password_regex = this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W]){1,})(?!.*\s).{6,}$/.test(value);
return password_regex;
```