# Android - Regex for password must contain a minimum of 8 in length including characters(Upper or Lower), at least one number?

Tags: android, regex

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a) related to javascript but it didn't work for me in android. I want to validate my password which must contain a minimum of 8 in length including characters(Upper or Lower), at least one number? (It should not contain any special symbols)

I have tried this it is working fine with only lower case but not taking Upper case letters.

```
private boolean isPasswordContainsNumericAndChars(String password) {
        /*^               # start-of-string
        (?=.*\d)          # a digit must occur at least once
        (?=.*[a-z])       # a lower case letter must occur at least once
        (?=.*[A-Z])       # an upper case letter must occur at least once
        (?=.*[@#$%^&+=])  # a special character must occur at least once you can replace with your special characters
        (?=\\S+$)         # no whitespace allowed in the entire string
        .{8,}             # anything, at least eight places though
        $                 # end-of-string*/
        final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

As he mentioned in the duplicate question which is not working in android.

> Minimum eight characters, at least one letter and one number:

```
 "^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$"
```

Comment: What did not work? What was the exception?

Comment: I have updated my question, please check it once @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: But you did not actually use the regex you said you found. Use it. `PASSWORD_PATTERN = "(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{8,}"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If I use the regex which you mentioned above, I must need to enter upper case letter also which is not my matching to the given requirement.

Comment: If you do not require an uppercase letter, remove that `(?=.*[A-Z])` lookahead, what is the problem?

Comment: Either it should take Lower with numeric or Upper with numeric

Comment: Then join the letter requiring lookaheads, `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])` => `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`

Comment: Let me try this `"(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}"`

Comment: Yeah great. Finally `final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}";` this one is working. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228947/discussion-between-shailendra-madda-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally this `"(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}"` regex worked.

```
public static boolean isPasswordContainsNumericAndCharsWithMin8InLength(String password) {
        /*^               # start-of-string
        (?=.*\d)          # a digit must occur at least once
        (?=.*[a-z])       # a lower case letter must occur at least once
        (?=.*[A-Z])       # an upper case letter must occur at least once
        (?=.*[@#$%^&+=])  # a special character must occur at least once you can replace with your special characters
        (?=\\S+$)         # no whitespace allowed in the entire string
        .{8,}             # anything, at least eight places though
        $                 # end-of-string*/
        final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```