# Password validation using javaScript , not working correctly

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

this is my email address validation using JavaScript, I have only two conditions that work, the one with the special character is not working.
Only the third is tested on the email address, the first two are on the password.
Please help me.

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
        function validateEmail(form) {
            var tr = /[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}/
            var tr2 = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/  
            var tr3 = /[A-Za-z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.!$+/?_]/
            if (!(tr.test(form.password.value))){
                alert("The passowrd length must be more than 8 letters.")
                return false;
            }
            else if (!(tr3.test(form.password.value))){
                alert("Enter a special character.")
                return false;
            }
            else if (!(tr2.test(form.email.value))){
                alert("Enter a valid email.")
                return false;
            }
            else{
                alert("signed in successfully")
                window,open("HomePage.html")
                return true
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: ```I have only two conditions that work, the one with the special character is not working.``` doesn't help people understand your question. What is your expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Why is the title about email validation but question itself about the password?

Comment: See this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)

Comment: You can find tools online to help testing your regular expressions, https://regexfiddler.com/ or https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change regex to this.

```js
const form = {
  password: {
    value: 'buffaloBill3#@$',
  },
  email: {
    value: 'hannibal@lecter.com'
  }
};


function validateEmail(form) {
  var tr = /[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}/
  var tr2 = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/
  var tr3 = /^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{0,}$/;
    
  if (!(tr.test(form.password.value))) {
    alert("The passowrd length must be more than 8 letters.")
    return false;
  } else if (!(tr3.test(form.password.value))) {
    alert("Enter a special character.")
    return false;
  } else if (!(tr2.test(form.email.value))) {
    alert("Enter a valid email.")
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("signed in successfully")
    window, open("HomePage.html")
    return true
  }
}

validateEmail(form);
```