# Javascript validate password field input

Tags: javascript

i want to validate a password field with the following conditions:
One uppercase character
One lowercase character
One number
One special character
Eight characters minimum
If the password input is correct i want to make the pass field green if not it should be red.
I tried with this code but doesnt work:

```
let password = document.querySelectorAll(".control-group")[3];
password.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let inp = password.value;
  if (
    inp.match(/[a-z]/g) &&
    inp.match(/[A-Z]/g) &&
    inp.match(/[0-9]/g) &&
    inp.match(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g) &&
    inp.length >= 8
  ) {
    password.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    password.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)

Comment: Please add more details like html and css in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's not working because `inp.match(/[a-z]/g) && inp.match(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g)` is like `if (true == false) {...}`. Take a look at what @HarshSaini said.

Answer (score 0):

Output of match() is not true or false, but the match thing like str or int or if it wrong it will show null. So in your case better use "if your case (if input.match() != null) as true". There is the example !

```js
var input = "GoodMorning Sir"

if (input.match(/[0-9]/g) != null){
  console.log("there are number here")
} else if (input.match(/[A-Z]/g) != null){
  console.log("there are uppercase here")
}

//this is your if else code, try to console.log your condition
//as you can see it wont giving output true or false
console.log(input.match(/[A-Z]/g)) // ["G", "M" , "S"]
```

Comment: In javascript, 'null' is like 'true', an example: `let i = 2; if (i) {/* This is true */}`, and `let i = null; if (i) { /* This is false */ }` An example: [W3 reproducer](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GSZ5D2V2T50N)

Comment: yah that's a goo example, i'll add it to my answer @NakarukatoshiUzumaki

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is not working due to the fact that

```
inp.match(/[a-z]/g) && inp.match(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g)
```

is just "false". You are telling there "if it contains alphabetic characters as well as it doesn't contains any", which is some sort of

```
let i = 0;
if (i == 1) {...}
```

As I said on one of the comments of your question, just search for another solution, like the one that @harsh-saini said.

Comment: `password.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let checkPass =
    "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-zd@$!%*?&]{8,}$";
  if (checkPass.test(password.value)) password.style.backgroundColor = "#c0eb34";
  else password.style.backgroundColor = "#FF374E";
});`    tried this one but doesnt work, it throws the error, checkPass.test is not a function

Comment: checkpass is meant to be a regex, not a String. String doesn't have the "test" function, try `let checkPass = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-zd@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;`.

Comment: i tried like you said with the following code: `let passwordField = document.getElementById("password");
passwordField.addEventListener("focusout", () => {
  let checkPass =
    /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-zd@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;
  if (checkPass.test(password.value)) {
    passwordField.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    console.log("green");
  } else {
    passwordField.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("red");
  }
});` but only makes i red even if the password has all the conditions