# HTML Password Validation - Need a special character mandatory but not a digit (number)

Tags: html, validation, passwords

Need to set a validation for password where the use case is "Password must require 1 Upper Case, 1 Special Character and at least 6 characters"

Currently using Pattern:

```
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}"
```

However, If I enter password as John@doe - it still asks to enter a digit (number). I presume it is because of `(?=.*\d)`, but if I remove this, then password is accepted without any special character.

How can I use a pattern where it asks for Special Character but not a digit (number)?

Answer (score 1):

Just an update - following pattern worked

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$
```

Adding Description/Breakdown:

Earlier `(?=.*\d)` was consuming both numbers & special characters - not sure why. But separating them as below helps to resolve this.

At least one upper case English letter, `(?=.*?[A-Z])`
At least one lower case English letter, `(?=.*?[a-z])`
At least one digit, `(?=.*?[0-9])`
At least one special character, `(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])`
Minimum six in length `.{6,}` (with the anchors)

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19605207/10926448

Comment: Please provide a short description how your answer solves the problem. thank you!