# Regex for username with length 6-8 and at most 2 numbers and the rest are letters in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to do this but it is not working...

`^(?=.*\d+\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[\dA-Za-z]{6,8}$`

Comment: i would just do this in code

Comment: I agree with @pm100 - unless you _really_ need this in a `RegularExpressionAttribute`, having it in code would be much simpler and testable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for password must contain at least eight characters, at least one number and both lower and uppercase letters and special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)

Comment: Sounds like you could adjust your pattern to [something like this](https://regex101.com/r/GJcb43/1).