# Dynamic Password Validate in Postman API automatically

Tags: javascript

I have written the script in Postman to generate automatic email and password every time call the API but have a requirement that the password should be 1 upper case, 1 lower case, 1 special character, 1numeric value, and a minimum of 8 characters long. So, I want to validate whether the generated password met the requirement or not. So what will I write in the test tab to validate this?

Comment: You can learn regex expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a